# How can I move a block from homepage? I only know the identifier, but I can't find it in code

Tags: magento2

How can I move a block from homepage?
I only know the identifier,it's "block-homepage", but when I search for "block-homepage" in the code I can't find anything .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into the default.xml file under your theme's layout folder. If it's there, you can remove it with the single line below.

```
<referenceBlock name="block-homepage" remove="true" />
```

Or maybe you're looking to a page created from the admin dashboard.

Goto **Content -> Pages** and look for your page. Select **Edit** from action menu you and check the **Content** section. You may see the block inside of the HTML code like below.

```
<div>{{block name="block-homepage" template="yourtemplate.phtml"}}</div>
```

Comment: I have searched all the code for block-homepage and didn't found anything

Comment: I have found the block using your second suggestion, thank you!

Comment: @AndreeaOnica You're welcome. I'm glad it helped.